# jQuery Waypoints and changing nav class depend on current section

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I want to change nav (fixed navigation) color depend on the current section, but get stuck with waypoints. When I call it, else statement never execute. Any ideas?

```
    var mainNav = $('.navigation');
    var section = $('section'),
    white = $("section[data-color='white']"),
    black = $("section[data-color='black']");


    $('section').waypoint(function(){
        if (white) {
            mainNav.removeClass('light');
        }
        else {
            mainNav.addClass('light');
        }

    });
```

White and black are jQuery objects, not HTMLElements. The element option in Waypoints expects a plain ol' element. So I've used jQuery extension that the library provides. The one below is work perfectly.

```
        var mainNav = $('.navigation');
        var $section = $('section'),
        white = $("section[data-color='white']"),
        black = $("section[data-color='black']");

    white.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
            mainNav.removeClass('light');
            if (direction == 'up') {
                mainNav.addClass('light');
            }
        }
    });

    black.waypoint({
        handler: function (direction) {
            mainNav.addClass('light');
            if (direction == 'up') {
                mainNav.removeClass('light');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try using `white.length`

Comment: It's not working with `white.length` either.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or show relevant HTML Code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5powcfpf/

Comment: In which file / line do you get the error?

Comment: @JLow  jquery.waypoints.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: did you find solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The else statement never execute because the variable in the if() never change the "white" variable is always true and is equals to what is initialized. Try this :

```
 var mainNav = $('.navigation');
    var section = $('section'),
    white = $("section[data-color='white']"),
    black = $("section[data-color='black']");


    $('section').waypoint(function(){
        if (this.element == white[0]) {
            mainNav.removeClass('light');
        }
        else {
            mainNav.addClass('light');
        }

    });
```

The idea is to check if the element that triggered your waypoint is equals to white or black or....

Comment: Exactly @jpprade, but your code is not working either. Actually only the last code I've updated is working as I want.